# using variables to set a div position using .css

Tags: jquery, css, variables, position, statements

I have a bridge teaching website which includes a card play option:

```
<a href="http://bridgeplays.com/test100.html">bridgeplays.com/test100.html</a>`
```

Which I am happy with. However I wish to reduce my setup time for each new game I produce.
For each game I have to position 52 divs for each card which I do as follows for the spade ace.

**CSS:**

```
#SA{
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    top: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "card" id = "SA">
    <img src = "http://www.bridgeplays.com /images/SA.png">
</div>
```

I would like to be able to reduce the time I spend changing the CSS left and top parameters for each card. There are 52 positions each card is to be allocated to.  I would like to be able to assign each combination of left and top to one variable that could be used to set the card position perhaps via a          `$("#SA").CSS-----` statement. I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
var SAPos= " left:380px,top:250px ";
$("#SA").css({SAPos);
```

I've tried a few combinations of defining SAPos, but with no success.

Comment: Jquery css doesn't work like that... check the api doc for that prototype here: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: have you looked into LESS or SASS? They offer something like CSS variables. (from your description it's not really clear what you want to achieve with those variables)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the attributes and values should not be separated by spaces:

```
 <div class="card" id="SA">
     <img src="http://www.bridgeplays.com /images/SA.png">
  </div>
```

Second, the `.css()` function needs both curly braces:

```
var SAPos= " left:380px,top:250px ";

$("#SA").css({SAPos});
```

**EDIT**
You can use an object to store the variables:

```
var SAPos = {
  'left' : '380px',
  'top' : '250px'
}
$("#SA").css(SAPos);
```

Comment: Yes thanks for that. The curly bracket omission was a typo mistake .

Comment: Yes thanks for the reply. The curly bracket omission was a typo mistake . However the SAPos variable doesn't move the spade ace image (#SA) to  position   left:380px top:250px. The variable is accepted, but has no positioning affect.